# how to design database if one column's value is based on past time and another column's value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, redis

suppose i was design a word remember app.
there is a table called 'memory'

column structure like this

**word | last_memo_time | last_memo_value | current_memo_value**

and let's say
**current_memo_value = forgotten_function(last_memo_time,last_memo_value)**

my question is, how to design this whole thing?

should i just create a schedule event in mysql, and update each row periodically ? (i think that would be a bad idea when records increse more and more.)

or should i just record the static data inside database, and calculate the dynamic value in API layer(web server)? (i think that would not ok for whole table sorting)

what is your suggestion?

Comment: The latter option: since the result of the function call is just computed, and not original, data, you should lean towards generating it at the time you query.

Comment: yes, count one effective solution. create a plus column and calculate when querying

Comment: What do you mean by "past time"?

Comment: past time means the duration since the last time I remember one word